# Problema para asignar certificado ssl a un sitio web para que la pagina tenga https desde el servidor windows server 2012 Satandard

Tags: servidor, ssl, https, certificado-ssl, windows-server-2012

Estoy tratando de que una pagina web tenga el protocolo https, pero la pagina no reconoce el certificado.

1.- El sitio estaba alojado en el hosting (hostingplus) contratado.

2.- Se trasladó el sitio a otro servidor y junto a esto se cambiaron los DNS (cloudflare) lo cual quedo apuntando de manera correcta al acceder al sitio web.

3.- Se necesita que el sitio tenga instalado un certificado SSL. Se intentó hacerlo con uno ya instalado en el servidor nuevo de la misma forma como se ha realizado con otros sitios que tenemos alojados allí (lo cual funcionan ok).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Pero al ejecutar la página nos el siguiente error ilustrada en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se puede solucionar esto para que tenga Https el sitio?
¿Por qué no me resulta con los certificados que tengo instalado en el servidor nuevo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema aquì es que **estas definiendo una IP especifica (10.10.10.9) lo cual no es correcto**, no definas una IP (All Unassigned), tu configuracion debe ser similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo intente, pero no me resulta